# Работа с переменными в bat

Tags: cmd, bat, скрипт

Сейчас объединяю значения двух переменных через временный файл. А хотелось бы обойтись без файлов, чтобы красивее было, и быстрее тоже. Подскажите как можно это сделать?

```
set region=N16-
wmic bios get serialnumber | findstr /V SerialNumber > 0.tmp
set /p serial="" <0.tmp
del 0.tmp
cls
echo %region%%serial:~0,7%| clip
```

Этот код делает следующее:

1. Создаем переменную **region** с значением "N16-"
2. Узнаем серийный номер компьютера и записываем его в файл
3. Создаем переменную **serial** и кладем в нее содержимое файла
4. Удаляем файл
5. Выводим объединённые переменные и кладем их в буфер обмена

Проблема во второй строке: никак не могу нагуглить как вывод команды положить сразу в переменную, минуя чехарду с файлами?

Пробую так:

```
FOR /F "usebackq skip=1" %i IN (`wmic bios get serialnumber`) DO echo %i | clip
```

Но вывод команды многострочный. В итоге в буфере обмена лежит строка: **Режим вывода команд на экран (ECHO) включен.**

Comment: *как вывод команды положить сразу в переменную, минуя чехарду с файлами?* Через FOR /F ('команда').

Comment: Пробую делать так:

Comment: См: тему assign-command-output-to-variable-in-batch-file https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16203629/assign-command-output-to-variable-in-batch-file

Comment: *Но вывод команды многострочный* А findstr куда дел? верни обратно в текст команды. Или в цикле проверяй наличие нужной подстроки вместо тупого echo, и загоняй значение в переменную только когда подстрока найдена. И не забудь про enabledelayedexpansion.

Answer (score 1):

Вот самый короткий вариант, который удалось сделать:

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set serial=none
FOR /F "usebackq skip=1" %%i IN (`wmic bios get serialnumber`) DO IF !serial!==none set serial=%%i
ECHO N16-%serial%| clip
```

---

Если кто может лучше, буду рад посмотреть другие варианты.

Answer (score 0):

Пришел к такому варианту:

```
FOR /F "tokens=2 delims==" %%i in ('wmic bios get serialnumber /VALUE') ^
    do powershell -command "Rename-Computer -NewName N16-%%i"
```

Получаем серийник, формируем имя и СРАЗУ переименовываем компьютер.

Comment: А почему вы дали на ваш вопрос новый ответ, а не дополнили предыдущий?

Comment: Открою вам тайну: всё можно реализовать сразу в PowerShell.

Comment: откройте, звучит интересно!